# how to jump to different frame in video

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, video

CLO meeting notes

I am trying to create a video in my web app and let the user being able to click button on the page to jump to certain farm of the video.

I have something like

```
<video width="720" height="640" controls>
    <source src='/assets/video/test.mp4' type="video/mp4">
</video>    
<a href='#'>15 sec mark</a>
<a href='#'>25 sec mark</a>
<a href='#'>35 sec mark</a>
```

I have looked at js video page

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp

but it doesn't seem to provide the method or solution for it.

Can anyone given me any suggestions? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [this documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video) which is more complete :

```
var mediaElement = document.getElementById('mediaElementID');
mediaElement.seekable.start();  // Returns the starting time (in seconds)
mediaElement.seekable.end();    // Returns the ending time (in seconds)
mediaElement.currentTime = 122; // Seek to 122 seconds
mediaElement.played.end();      // Returns the number of seconds the browser has played
```

Using an `onclick` event on the `<a/>` tag you should be able to set the `currentTime` property easily :

```
<video id="mediaElementID" width="720" height="640" controls>
    <source src='/assets/video/test.mp4' type="video/mp4">
 </video>    
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('mediaElementID').currentTime = 15">15 sec mark</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

Check out [this docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video). `mediaElement.currentTime = 15` should do the trick.